# error: object tools is not a member of package scala var value: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala-2.10

I'm using

- IntelliJ IDEA 126.330
- Scala plugin 0.7.142
- JVM 1.6
- Scala 2.10
- Under Windows 7 x64

Decided to try Scala and wrote following application

```
object main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

Then I created Scala Console Run Configuration. When I'm trying to run it I get following output in console

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin\java" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:16352,suspend=y,server=n -Djline.terminal=NONE -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\work\scala-2.10.0-RC2\lib\scala-compiler.jar;C:\work\scala-2.10.0-RC2\lib\scala-library.jar;C:\work\scala-2.10.0-RC2\lib\scala-reflect.jar;C:\Users\root\.IntelliJIdea12\config\plugins\Scala\lib\scala-plugin-runners.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 126.330\lib\idea_rt.jar" org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.rt.ConsoleRunner -classpath "C:/Users/root/IdeaProjects/testScala/out/production/testScala;C:/work/scala-2.10.0-RC2/lib/scala-actors.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/jce.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/resources.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/jsse.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/rt.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/charsets.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/deploy.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/management-agent.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/javaws.jar;C:/work/scala-2.10.0-RC2/lib/scala-library.jar;C:/work/scala-2.10.0-RC2/lib/scala-swing.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar;" -usejavacp2 -Y2log-classpath
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:16352', transport: 'socket'
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0-RC2 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_32).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> <console>:5: error: object tools is not a member of package scala
  var value: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain = _
                   ^
<console>:6: error: object tools is not a member of package scala
  def set(x: Any) = value = x.asInstanceOf[scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain]
                                                 ^
```

After googling I found suggestion to pass `-usejavacp` parameter to the app. It helped to get rid of errors but application is not being executed. All I see in console is

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin\java" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:16383,suspend=y,server=n -Djline.terminal=NONE -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\work\scala-2.10.0-RC2\lib\scala-compiler.jar;C:\work\scala-2.10.0-RC2\lib\scala-library.jar;C:\work\scala-2.10.0-RC2\lib\scala-reflect.jar;C:\Users\root\.IntelliJIdea12\config\plugins\Scala\lib\scala-plugin-runners.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 126.330\lib\idea_rt.jar" org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.rt.ConsoleRunner -classpath "C:/Users/root/IdeaProjects/testScala/out/production/testScala;C:/work/scala-2.10.0-RC2/lib/scala-actors.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/jce.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/resources.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/jsse.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/rt.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/charsets.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/deploy.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/management-agent.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/javaws.jar;C:/work/scala-2.10.0-RC2/lib/scala-library.jar;C:/work/scala-2.10.0-RC2/lib/scala-swing.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar;" -usejavacp -Y2log-classpath
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:16383', transport: 'socket'
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0-RC2 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_32).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

I also tried disabling Scala Compile Server in IDE Options. Didn't help either.

How do I fix it ?

Comment: Use `Application` Run/Debug configuration, not a console.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yeah, App conf works. But what scala console configuration is for then ?

Comment: For running Scala interactive console.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, Serge, could you please post your response as an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **Application** run configuration type. Scala console is to run the interactive console, not an app.

Answer (score 0):

this should fix your issue
see the following link
http://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/error-value-tools-is-not-a-member-of-package-scala-when-using-the-scala-console-in-intellij-idea/

Comment: I removed the exception but my app doesn't execute.